# He wouldn't have done that!

Tags: grammar

A: I'm sure he stole the money.

> B1: No. He couldn't have done that!
>
> B2: No. He wouldn't have done that!
>
> B2: No. He mightn't have done that!

May I ask the difference between B1,B2 and B3?

Comment: Although there is nothing technically wrong with *mightn't*, it's a contraction that's rarely used. Instead, it's normally written in its full version: *might not*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B1 is saying that he literally could not have done it, which implies that the speaker believes that it was impossible for the man to have done it.

B2 is saying that he would not have done that, which implies that the speaker doesn't believe that the man did it. This shows that speaker is familiar with the man, and knows him well enough to know that what was done was not something the man would voluntarily do.

B3 is saying that he might not have done that, which means that the speaker doesn't feel too strongly about whatever happened. The speaker is pointing out that there is the possibility that the man did not do it, but in doing that, the speaker is also pointing out the possibility that the man did do it.

Comment: The third sentence is strange both because you would not normally use an exclamation mark after *might* and because you would not normally use a contracted form of *might not*.

Comment: Thanks @Eliza Xie. That was so helpful. May I ask if all of these three sentences are 3rd conditionals or not?

Comment: @samsam No problem. I would say the sentences aren't conditionals, because you can't put them into an "if...then" format. For example, B1 says "He couldn't have done that", but there is no structure of a hypothetical, and the following consequence. B1 isn't saying that "if...then he couldn't have done that", but B1 is making a statement saying that he didn't.